# How to change default notification sound with Firebase?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can get notification data with

```
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
```

But I don't know how to use it when my app is on background. The data I receive from Firebase is like this

```
%@ [AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_l"): DEFGH, AnyHashable("sound"): alert.aiff, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 1515722730, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.sound2"): default, AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = ABC;
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): xxxxxx, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:xx%xx]
```

Easy APNs Provider plays custom sound just fine though.

Comment: You can through the notification in iOS 10 more devices + speech to push content, fixed audio broadcast on iOS 10 the following equipment

Comment: I don't get what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

just disable sound from fireBase console and when your notification recieved use custom sound and call this method when your notification recieved

import AVFoundation
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound() {

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundName", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)


    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    guard let player = player else { return }

    player.play()

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

}

Comment: Will that work if my app is killed or in background? I don't think so.

Comment: use notification service extension and  from backend side assign mutable_content : true